# Removing a grant number from a published paper

Tags: academic-life

How can I remove a grant number from the acknowledgment of a published paper? since my institution refused to pay the reward for publishing this paper.

Comment: How refused? did they told you at the beginning that they will pay and then decided to not pay? or you just assumed they will pay the fees??

Comment: If you were supported by the grant the acknowledgment should stay, even if you think the institution has reneged on some promised "reward".